# Aterisk/Freeswitch SIP user generation through web application

Tags: php, web-services, node.js, asterisk, freeswitch

I am very much new to Asterisk/freeswitch integration to web apps running on PHP,Node.js or any other server side languages.What i would like to achieve is to create a new SIP user in Asterisk/Freeswitch conf files or database files from within a web application. How can i modify/write the  config files or SIP database on these Asterisk/Freeswitch PBX software hosted in the same server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your purpose in multiple way.
Maybe the simplest and the direct is to add in sip.conf (asterisk) a few lines that describe the new user, like described in [here](http://doxygen.asterisk.org/trunk/Config_sip.html). Then you just need to restart asterisk (or better to call a reload config through Asterisk cli.
Here is a maybe useful link: [Asterisk php cli](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asteriskcmd/).
For freeswitch is the same, but you have to enter the new user in xml format, as specified in [this page](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/XML_User_Directory_Guide).
Maybe if you use asterisk or freeswitch over a db it will be even simpler: just add a line in the db!

Be sure to verify user input to create only valid user (block xml tags, hashes, ; and other dangerous symbol)

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk and freeswitch is compleatly different.

For asterisk you can use Asterisk Realtime Architecture(ARI), it just describe tables in database.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime+Sip

Unfortanly you can't "just add users", you need understand voip basic.

Also you can write text config files, for example of how to do that see Freepbx.org project.